# Python: почему эти два регулярных выражения re.sub и re.compile не проводят замену?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

почему эти два регулярных выражения re.sub и re.compile не проводят замену?

если я использую простые регулярные выражения, замена проходит успешно

**re.findall** хорошо работает. Я хочу заменить пустым **' '**. но **re.sub** и **re.compile** не работает с этим конкретным регулярным выражением

```
if len(re.findall('(?!<p>).+?(?<!</p>)$', page_text)) != 0:
                page_text = re.sub('(?!<p>).+?(?<!</p>)$', '', page_text)
                counter_img += 1
```

**ИЛИ**

```
    if len(re.findall('^\s+</p>', page_text)) != 0:
        page_text = re.compile(r'', page_text)
        counter_img += 1
```

**ИЛИ**

```
        if len(re.findall('\n\s*', page_text)) != 0:
            page_text = re.sub('\n\s*', '', page_text)
            counter_img += 1
```

Comment: не можете заменить re.sub or re.compile на что?

Comment: как видите, с пустым ' '

Comment: Понятно. То есть вопрос не в замене re.sub или re.compile на что-то другое, а "почему они не работают, как ожидается?"

Comment: точно. что-то не работает на заменяемой детали

Comment: Такое впечатление, что русский язык вам не родной (я серьёзно). Предложил изменения, чтобы остальные могли понять лучше запрос.

Comment: И приведите лучше примеры page_text - с чем не работает - что должно быть, и что получается.

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось добавить флаг типа **flags=re.MULTILINE**
Я снова тестирую, и теперь работает нормально

```
    if len(re.findall('(?!<p>).+?(?<!</p>)$', page_text, flags=re.MULTILINE)) != 0:
        page_text =  re.sub('(?!<p>).+?(?<!</p>)$', '', page_text, flags=re.MULTILINE) 
        counter_img += 1
```

см. эти ссылки

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668591/string-replacement-multiline-case-insensitive-with-special-characters

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163586/python-regex-multiple-search

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html